# Express Middleware not setting CORS header

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, cors

I am trying to set the CORS headers on an express app and I can't figure out why It's not working:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
    if ("OPTIONS" == req.method){
        res.send(200);
    }
    console.log("Set CORS Header");
    next();
});
```

I have tried using res.header, res.setheader and res.append also and all have not set the header correctly, but the "Set CORS Header" message appears on the console everytime a request comes through.

Edit: looks like it might be something to do with AWS EC2?

The full server code is here: https://github.com/rossgriebenow/wkdu-music-webapp/blob/master/WKDU_SQL.js

Comment: What's the difference between `res.append` and `res.set`  ?

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried the express cors its much simpler and destroy the need of setting your cors manually first install it using this :

```
yarn add cors
//if u use yarn
npm install cors --save
//if u use npm
```

after that use it in your middleware like this :

```
//for example
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

you can also see another method this module have in this github page https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: oh i see you are using aws i think you should open port first in aws have you open that port?

Comment: yes, the page loads but all the non-static endpoints don't work because of the CORS issue.